# I need a function that abides by this definition: $F(x+1)-F(x)=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find a solution to the differential equation:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\lfloor{x}\rfloor.$$
And one solution is $$F(x+1)-F(x)=x.$$
I do not know any strategies to determine the definition of the function $F(x)$. I have seen that some Riemann functions have some functional definitions like this, and I was wondering if anyone knows a function that has the definition: $F(x+1)-F(x)=x$.

Comment: A quadratic might fit the bill. Try finding a solution of the form $F(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$. Note also that you can choose $c = 0$ freely.

Comment: Try $\frac 12\times (x^2-x)$.

Comment: My first try would be telescope.

Comment: @lulu $1/2\times(x^2-x)$ worked, thank you.

Comment: @BilalSalha You don't specify the domain of the differential equation, which is rather critical here. There exist no solutions $\,y=f(x)\,$ on $\mathbb{R}$, or in fact on any open interval that includes an integer. That's because the derivative $\,y'\,$ of any differentiable function has the [Darboux (a.k.a. intermediate value) property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), while $\,\lfloor x \rfloor\,$ does not since it has [jump discontinuities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Jump_discontinuity) at all integer values.

Comment: @dxiv, I agree with your comment. If someone's looking for solutions in a weaker sense than usual, IMO they should say that. Presumably in this context "solution" means "continuous, and differentiable except possibly on a countable set, and satisfies the DE everywhere it is differentiable."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is $$ f(x) = (1/2)x(x-1)$$

Notice that $$ f(x+1)-f(x) = (1/2) x (x+1) - (1/2) x(x-1) =x$$

The way that I came up with this form was to differentiate the equation twice and notice that $$ f''(x+1)=f''(x).$$

Thus $$f''(x)=C$$ which implies that $ f(x)$ is a polynomial.

Find the coefficients from the given equation and you have the solution.

Comment: Cool stuff. Thanks.

Comment: $f''(x) = constant$, not necessarily 0.

Comment: Thanks for attention.  Good question. I liked it so much.

Comment: @Nick   Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct to me. If I'm reading the question correctly, $\lfloor x \rfloor$ refers to the integer floor of $x$, in which case that DE probably won't have a polynomial solution.

Comment: @goblin yes, this is far too continuous for the floor function. I'm trying to figure out what to do with this, as it is definitely the correct shape.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just solve it separately on each interval?

As I understand it, on each interval $[a,a+1)$ the DE read $$\frac{dy}{dx}=a$$ which has solution $y = ax, x \in [a,a+1).$ And you can add a constant to get a new solution of course.

So now just patch them together to get something continuous:

- If $x \in [0,1)$ then $y = 0$.
- If $x \in [1,2)$ then $y = x-1$.
- If $x \in [2,3)$ then $y = 2x-4$
- etc.

Comment: Yes, I did that originally, and I posted for someone to find one solution that contained this relationship.